# Как в JAVA создать динамическую таблицу для ввода матрицы, используя JTable

Tags: java, swing, матрицы, jtable, grid-layout

Как в JAVA создать динамическую таблицу для ввода матрицы, используя JTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Структура и данные хранятся в TableModel.

Формируете нужную вам TableModel, можете использовать DefaultTableModel и подставляете в JTable.

Подробно можно посмотреть здесь https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html